# How can I show hidden div with angularjs by url

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How do I access the page below and show the div CertificateRegister instead of div EmailRegister via URL, for example www.mysite.com/register#CertificateRegister

```js
eAssinatura.controller('CadastroController', ['$scope', '$route', '$routeParams', '$location', '$http', '$modal', 'blockService', 'notifyService', 'browserService', 'locale',
        function ($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location, $http, $modal, blockService, notifyService, browserService, locale) {
          
          //$scope.EmailRegister = true; // setting the div register by e-mail visible when the page loads
    //$scope.CertificateRegister = false;
    //$scope.showEmailRegister = function () {
    //    $scope.EmailRegister = true;
    //    $scope.CertificateRegister = false;
    //};
    //$scope.showCertificateRegister = function () {
    //    if (!$scope.LoadedPKI) { //setting PKI when register by certificate is selected
    //        init(); 
    //    } 
    //    $scope.EmailRegister = false;
    //    $scope.CertificateRegister = true; 
    //};

    $scope.RegisterDisplay = false;
    if ($location.path() == '/CertificateRegister') {
        $scope.RegisterDisplay = true;
    }
          
         }
        ]);
```

```html
     <div ng-show="RegisterDisplay">
                                <p>E-mail Register</p>
          <a href="#" ng-click="showEmailRegister()">Don' t Have Digital Certificate »</a>
                            </div>
                            <div ng-hide="RegisterDisplay">
                                <p>Certificate Register</p>
                              <a href="#" ng-click="showCertificateRegister()">Have Digital Certificate »</a>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of your controller you can:

```
$scope.RegisterDisplay = false;
if ($location.path() == '/CertificateRegister') {
    $scope.RegisterDisplay = true;
}
```

In your html you should be able to do something like this:

```
<div id="certregister" ng-show="RegisterDisplay">//This is your CertificateRegister div</div>

<div id="EmailRegister" ng-hide="RegisterDisplay">//This is your EmailRegister div</div>
```

Comment: It works, but the link 
<a href="#" ng-click="showEmailRegister()">Don' t Have Digital Certificate »</a>
and
<a href="#" ng-click="showCertificateRegister()">Have Digital Certificate »</a> doesn't work

Comment: Did you change the code in those functions to change the value of $scope.RegisterDisplay accordingly?

Comment: Dear @john-halbert I change my code like you suggest. Look my new code. But showCertificateRegister and showEmailRegister doen't work

Comment: Is the edited code above current? Looks like you commented out those functions. Should be something like `$scope.showEmailRegister = function(){$scope.RegisterDisplay = false}` and `$scope.showCertificateRegister = function(){if (!$scope.LoadedPKI) {init()} $scope.RegisterDisplay = true}`

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding url variable in your route then have controller watch for that and show/hide div

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [`ui-router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) you can add an optional parameter to the state, and take that parameter in your `controller` using the `$stateProvider` like [this example](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#basic-parameters)

You probably would do something like:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('register', {
        url: "/register/:emailRegister",
        templateUrl: '.html',
        controller: function ($stateParams) {
            // If we got here from a url of /register/true
            if($stateParams.emailRegister){
              $scope.showCertificateRegister();
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using $routeProvider for routing?

If so, you can create a parameter and read it in your controller.

route:

```
$routeProvider.when('/register/:showParam?', {...});
```

controller:

```
if ($route.current.params.showParam === 'CertificateRegister') {
    $scope.CertificateRegister = true;
}
```

*I you should add some validations (undefined, toLowerCase)